# Involutory symmetric commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for all candidate **symmetric** matrices A and B so that
$A^{-1}=A$, $B^{-1}=B$ and $AB=BA$. For any size or in dimension 4 if it's convenient.

Since A and B are involutory, they must be square roots of the identity (and not necessarily diagonal, correct me if I'm wrong).
Also, their symmetry implies that they are orthogonal matrices.

They are also orthogonally diagonalisable and can be written $P^{-1}DP$ or ${}^tPDP$ with $D$ diagonal made of roots of 1 and $P$ orthogonal.

Are they still not necessarily diagonal ?
Do you have any example of non diagonal ones ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: commuting diagonalisable matrices are simultaneously diagonalisable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question, but don't seem to realize it.

Let D_1 and D_2 be two diagonal matrices with only -1's and 1's on the diagonal. They commute (as diagonal matrices tend to do) which is good, but they look a bit too boring (since they are diagonal). Then the (not necessarily diagonal) matrices $P^{-1}D_1P$ and $P^{-1}D_2P$ (*using the same $P$!*) will also commute and hence produce the example you are looking for.

The theorem Lord Shark mentions is a jewel of linear algebra and useful in many situations. However here you only needs its (pretty much trivial) converse: two commuting diagonal matrices will still commute when you 'simultaniously  un-diagonalize' them.

Comment: I thought I was missing something, but apparently not. Thank you both for your answers

Comment: I all honesty I only opened the question because I first misread it as 'involuntary symmetric commuting matrices', which certainly intrigued me!